# how to pass a response from the service to the controller Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a request in the service:

```
getCommentText(id: number) {
    var data = null
    this.$http.post(this.path + '/' + id + '/GetComment', data, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }).then(r => r.data);
}
```

and controller

```
    openComment($event) {
        this.commentid = $event.target.id;
        this.service.getCommentText(this.commentid);
    }
```

I need to transfer the response from the service back to the controller. What would eventually have: **var text = (response)** I tried to use subscribe in the controller. But it does not work for me. This is the first Angulyar and I do not know him very well. How should I do it?

Comment: you need to take a better look at services in Angular this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services) might help

Comment: @RahulSingh OP has tagged this with AngularJS (ie v1.x)

Comment: ohh sorry @Phil it looks angularsynta

Comment: @RahulSingh you could be right and OP has just tagged this incorrectly or they could be using TypeScript with Angular 1.x

Comment: This is definitely Angular 1 code. Angular 2's http client returns an Observable which does not expose a `then` method unless you call `toPromise()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service should returns the promise:

```js
getCommentText(id: number) {
    var data = null
    return this.$http.post(this.path + '/' + id + '/GetComment', data, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }).then(r => r.data);
}

openComment($event) {
    this.commentid = $event.target.id;
    this.service.getCommentText(this.commentid).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post` returns a `Promise`. A `Promise` is an object which represents either a value or an error, both of which will occur at some point in the future. Since this is an object, it can be returned, like so:

```
getCommentText(id: number) {
  return this.$http.post(this.path + '/' + id + '/GetComment', data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(r => r.data);
}
```

This can then be consumed within your controller:

```
openComment($event) {
  this.commentid = $event.target.id
  this.service.getCommentText(this.commentid)
    .then((text) => {
      this.commentText = text
    })
```

Since `getCommentText` could fail, you should take care to also handle the failure case. Additionally, since this is asynchronous, consider displaying some kind of loading indicator to the user.